# ARROW_DOWN key not working in selenium ( Key Down / Up events only make sense for modifier keys.)

Tags: java, selenium

I am using **ARROW_DOWN** key in selenium, but it's not working, this is my code. I also used to **ENTER**, which is working fine, but with **ARROW_DOWN**, I am getting the following error.

Key Down / Up events only make sense for modifier keys.

This is the code I'm using

```
WebElement domain = Driver.driver.findElement(By.id("feild_domain"));
if (domain.isDisplayed()) {
           //domain.click();
           Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
           Thread.sleep(2000);
           builder.moveToElement(domain).click().perform();
           Thread.sleep(4000);
           builder.keyDown(domain, Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
           Thread.sleep(4000);
           builder.keyDown(domain, Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
           //Action seriesOfActions= builder.keyDown(domain, Keys.ARROW_DOWN).contextClick().build();
           //Action seriesOfActions = builder.moveToElement(domain).click().sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).keyDown(domain, Keys.ARROW_DOWN).contextClick().build();
           //seriesOfActions.perform();
           }
```

The above code isn't working. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [JavaDoc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#keyDown-java.lang.CharSequence-) for accepted parameters of `keyDown`.

It states

> **Parameters:**
>   *key* - Either `Keys.SHIFT`, `Keys.ALT` or `Keys.CONTROL`. If the provided key is none of those, IllegalArgumentException is thrown.
>   *target* - WebElement to perform the action

So, when you want to use other keys you have to use `sendKeys`.

Use this :

```
builder.sendKeys(domain, Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform();
```